# Add blender ID as a login option for BSE

Tags: feature-request, login

On the SE login page could we get a option to login with a [Blender ID](https://www.blender.org/id/login)? kind of like in this picture:
[image: BSE login page]

There are other non-offical blender sites ([graphicall](http://graphicall.org), [rightclickselect](https://rightclickselect.com/p/)) that are already using the blender ID system for their logins.
It seems that BSE would be a great fit for it. SE already has the login with other sites option, and BSE is all about blender.

Now I know this is rather unlikely to happen, the login is shared across all SE sites, and BSE is the only place it would make sense. However I wanted to put the idea out there.

Comment: What are the actual benefits of being able to sign in with the blender ID as opposed to other logins?

Comment: @RayMairlot its blender's login, with ties through all blender services (and now in blender its self). Doesn't it seem that if there is a standard blender login a fully blender site should use it? As an aside, what are the benefits to login in with AOL?! as apposed to just creating a password for SE? Convenience through the community's already used sites.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a reason to add it if it doesn't actually do anything. Sites like blender.today use the blender ID so it can use my name and email address, add-ons use it so I can access textures on the blender cloud. My point is, they use the Blender ID because it adds functionality, not just for the sake of having another way of logging it. And no, I don't see the purpose of having all those other login methods, but that doesn't mean we should add another.